# How to change Video.js src URL dynamically using variables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, video.js, react-functional-component

I'm creating a form where the user selects from a list of items. These items are being pulled in from a json file. Each item has a video URL. The user may select multiple items from the list. When they click Next, they will see all the information for the 1st item they selected. If there is more than one selected item, then they click Next and see the information for the second item, and so on and so forth until they reach the last selected item.

I'm using Video.js to display the videos. It's set up as a React functional component. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to pass the video URL variable to the video component. It will display a video if there is only one src URL, but not multiple.

This is in my VideoJS.tsx file:

```
export const VideoJS = (props: any) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<videojs.Player | null>(null);
  const {options, onReady} = props;

  useEffect(() => {

    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add("vjs-big-play-centered");
      videoRef.current?.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log("player is ready");
        onReady && onReady(player);
      }));

    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources);
    }
  }, [onReady, options, videoRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <div ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoJS;
```

Then, in my Form.tsx file, I have something that looks like this:

```
const handlePlayerReady = (player: any) => {

    const playerRef = useRef(null);
    
    const videoJSOptions = {
      autoplay: true,
      controls: true,
      responsive: true,
      fluid: true,
    }
    
      playerRef.current = player;
    
      player.on('waiting', () => {
        videojs.log('player is waiting');
      })
    
      player.on('dispose', () => {
        videojs.log('player will displose');
      })
    }
```

I then map through the values of all of the selected items and display the VideoJS component:

```
<VideoJS 
  options={videoJSOptions} 
  onReady={handlePlayerReady} 
  source={video_url} 
  type="video/mp4"          
/>
```

I've tried various different setups, and while this does not give me an error, it doesn't display the videos. Any guidance would be much appreciated! I've searched all over SO and haven't quite found a solution that fits.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you reproduce the issue in codepen or sandbox.

Comment: I reproduced a bare-bones example: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dream-qchib8?file=/src/App.tsx. It's a bit different from my sample code above as I found that I could use a URL prop. When tested live, it shows a thumbnail of the video but the video gets a ```VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media. ``` and does not display.

Comment: The url inside the source object is empty.

Comment: @YardenBuzaglo any suggestions or pointers on how to ensure it's not empty?

Comment: When I inspect the element, the URL appears.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I managed to solve the issue. I'm posting it here in case it's helpful to someone else. I'm still figuring out the appropriate types for the props so that I can replace the current (props: any). Codesandbox has also been updated with this solution.

VideoJS.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";

export const VideoJS = (props: any) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<videojs.Player | null>(null);
  const { options, onReady, url } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add("vjs-big-play-centered");
      videoRef.current?.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log("player is ready");
        onReady && onReady(player);
      }));
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src({ src: url, type: "video/mp4" });
    }
  }, [onReady, options, url, videoRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <video ref={videoRef} src={url} controls className="video-js" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoJS;
```

App.tsx

```
const videoJSOptions = {
          autoplay: true,
          responsive: true,
          fluid: true
        };
    
    
        <VideoJS
          options={videoJSOptions}
          onReady={handlePlayerReady}
          url={video_url}
        />
```